# What process does a production company have to go through in order to obtain a 'high profile' actor/actress?

Tags: production, acting-career

While the definition of a *High Profile* actor/actress may be a bit subjective on its own; lets just figure it is determined by the *financial* (an objective quantifier) success of past movies.

What kind of channels must production companies go through in order to obtain these people.

Is it just as its displayed and parodied ("Have your people call my people") or do they actually interact with the performer directly explaining the plot, duties of the role, have them go through a formal audition, etc.  Or is there something in between that I have not thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer? It depends.

It may be a request casting, where the performer is specifically asked through their agent to try out for the part. In this case, there may be a formal audition.

Or the producer may simply offer to cast the performer without an audition, usually relying on a familiarity with the performer's past work as a basis.

Lastly, one or more of the actors can simply be friends of someone in production, and approached in a very informal manner.

All that to say, there are few to no hard-and-fast rules in the industry, and every performer has their own preferences and way of doing things.

Comment: I had a feeling it was this way, regardless, just didn't know if there is an actual 'formal' practice

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I randomly came across it and thought I could help out.

Look up what movies this person has done in the past, and contact the casting director from some of those movies. They usually have great relationships with talent and their management. Hire the casting director that can get you the connection.

It also helps to present a very professional front, with the material you are trying to get them interested in, to their management. Management is usually the best way to go, as agents are cool people and all, but their job is to work the deals: money, benefits, all that. Management is going to have a much more personal relationship with the client. You can look up management info all day long on IMDBPro.

Also, be prepared with an offer. Actors like to act, but they don't like to work for free. The price has to be right.

Comment: Your answer is worded as if the OP is the person/production attempting to do this... which does not appear to be the case. They seem to be *generally* asking how it's done, so this doesn't really answer the question, it's just advice to someone, like an indie production company, trying to hire a big name.

Comment: That's a little bit nit-picky. So I addressed it to OP directly instead of in general, the information I gave is still relevant and correct.